# about midnight meaning

Tags: meaning

All are requested to submit the assignment by 16-11-2018, 12 O' Clock midnight.

What is meaning of this I have to submit it by before 4 hours today or I have 28 more hours to do this?

Comment: Don't ask us.  Ask *them*. Seriously.

Comment: Please tell me about this ?

Comment: I can't tell you about this. The person who set the deadline can. Ask the person who set the deadline.  ***You can't trust anything anyone tells you here about this deadline***, we are unrelated parties guessing in the vacuum of the internet, from all over the world.  ***Ask the person who set the deadline***.

Comment: @DanBron Yes that's a good caveat, but can't you tell them the usual interpretation of  the day that midnight belongs to?

Comment: @Mitch No, because if I'm wrong, and OP acts on it (and if they're not going to ask on it, then they wouldn't have asked) *then OP gets screwed*.  That's not fair to anyone involved (and it's also just another way of saying what I already said). If we want to get ivory tower about this, this Q also has nothing to do with *English*. If you translate it into French, the problem remains. This question is misplaced here; both for OP's needs and for ours.

Comment: @DanBron You could say the same for absolutely everything on this site.

Comment: No @Mitch, you couldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression is ambiguous - and there is no way to resolve the ambiguity:

> Midnight marks the beginning and ending of each day in civil time
>   throughout the world. As the dividing point between one day and
>   another, midnight defies easy classification as either part of the
>   preceding day or of the following day. Though there is no global
>   unanimity on the issue, most often midnight is considered the start of
>   a new day and is associated with the hour 00:00. Even in locales with
>   this technical resolution, however, vernacular references to midnight
>   as the end of any given day may be common.
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midnight